# Select radio OnClick on DIV

Tags: jquery, html, label

I want to select a `RADIO button` when a click action is performed on a specific DIV. I am using following code and it is working fine but it is not validated by W3 as according to them, I cannot use DIV tag inside LABEL tag. I will not prefer JQuery as the whole work can be done using LABEL at proper place
Following is my code

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 padding"><label style="height:100%; width:100%;">
  <div class="boxtyle2">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="donate-option-box">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="ChangeGivingTextColor('10');" class="styled" value="10" name="asd">
      </div>
      <h4 id="giving10" style="color: rgb(241, 55, 133);"><span class="pink2 currencysymbol">$</span>10</h4>Text

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!--boxtyle2-->
  </label></div>
```

Can someone modify my code so I can use it with LABEL but if there is no option for LABEL then what should I do in JQuery ?

Comment: please explain properly , last line is not at all understood

Comment: instead of `div` can you use `span`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I can also not use span inside span :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code by which you can select radio onclick on div elements.

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
   $("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Though i am clear enough about your question but what i`ll answer according to my understanding.

First, labels are in-line elements where as div`s are block elements so it is obvious that you cannot use block elements inside an in-line element.

Secondly, for on-click action on a div you can use jQuery .click() method

**Example:**

```
 $("#divID").click(function(){
 alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 });
```